# Exclude some text from log output with syslog-ng

Tags: syslog-ng

i have log message

**"2020-11-06T14:28:19.171900+0000 Host-9999 1889 1889 DBG some part of the log"**

Is it possible to filter messages like this with syslog-ng functionality to have  such output

**"DBG some part of the log"**

Basically i need to exclude date, host, pid, pid in every log message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i raised it with rewrite function, and with regex

```
rewrite test{
subst("^.{0,54}", " ", value("MSG"));
};
```